# Insertion problem with Collection Type in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, types, collections, easyadmin

I got an issue with my CollectionField.
I explain my problem. I want to create a job, for which we can add one or more tasks. Each task can have several activities etc. When I insert 2+ tasks,
[everythings works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFm38.png).

But I have 2 problems:

- When I create a [task T1 with an activity A1 AND a task T2 with an activity A2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iufR5.png) and I save, I end up with [task T1 and activity A2 and task T2 without activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t98Kl.png).
- When I create a [task T1 with two activities A1 and A2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOMcc.png), I have an SQL problem :

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Here is my code inside **JobCrudController** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Job;
use App\Form\TaskType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CollectionField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class JobCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Job::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            AssociationField::new('sector', 'Secteur'),
            TextField::new('name', 'Nom du métier'),
            CollectionField::new('tasks', 'Tâche(s)')
                ->setEntryType(TaskType::class),
         ];
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setDefaultSort([
                'sector.name' => 'ASC',
                'name' => 'ASC',
            ])
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Métier')
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Métiers');
    }
}
```

Inside **TaskType**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Task;
use App\Form\ActivityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom de la tâche',
            ])
            ->add('activities', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'Activité(s)',
                'entry_type' => ActivityType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And **ActivityType** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Activity;
use App\Form\UnderActivityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom de l\'activité',
            ])
            ->add('underActivities', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'Sous-Activité(s)',
                'entry_type' => UnderActivityType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Activity::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve this, do you have any solutions?
Noé

Comment: Hi, try to add `'by_reference' => false,` to the `$resolver->setDefaults()` method

Comment: I've put the 'by_reference' like you said, in both, ActivityType & TaskType. I got the same issues.